# Entity Framework 6.1.1 and Large Model Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've a huge database with around +1100 tables in it, I am trying to use entity framework and split the tables to multiple different diagrams to avoid the model crashes issue, I've added around 300+ table successfully however i can't add any more tables to any of the diagrams even a new one. 
Every time I try to add any other table I got the following exception.

**Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:**

```
'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request. 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8() 
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action1 executing, Action1 executed) 
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.Execute(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadDataTable[T](String sql, Func2 orderByFunc, DataTable table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, IEnumerable1 filters, String[] filterAliases) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadRelationships(IEnumerable1 filters) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList1 filters) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel() 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List1 errors) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, List`1 errors) 
at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(EdmxHelper edmxHelper)'. 
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.7402465. 
Generating the model took 00:00:02.5080167.
```

Any suggestions?